# Which basic LEGO blocks exist with studs on top with the same rectangular shapes top and bottom

Tags: piece-information, size

With the number of top studs for length and width, and heights given as 1/3, 2/3, 1 etc,

What varieties are available? 1x1x1/3, 1x8x2/3, 2x2x1, for example.

What's the maximum size, length and width of such a block?

Are there basic blocks with fractional heights above 1?

Regarding odd lengths. I've seen bricks that are 1 and 3 studs wide or long, but none with odd measurements above 3.  Do any like that exist with odd length or width above 3? For example 2x5x1 or 2x7x1, or 5x6x1.

Comment: 2x2x1 is just a normal 2x2 brick though, right?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you refer to as "pin" is more commonly referred to as ["stud"](https://brickipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Stud). Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I'll accept stud as the correct term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have compiled a spreadsheet showing all known size according to Bricklink:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vwCvSBmvaGz-Ucl1lTXI4tS55k6w1b2ih2mItxAWiis/edit?usp=sharing

It's hard to say what the 'largest' brick is, but here is some interesting data (only counting unmodified, rectangular parts):

- The part with the largest footprint is [Baseplate 50 x 50](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4186a) (discontinued)
- The part with the largest volume is [Brick 12 x 24](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30072) (also discontinued)
- The only part (I believe) with fractional height above 1/3 is a [Brick 1 x 1 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=86996)

Some other interesting dimensioned parts:

- [Brick 1 x 3 x 5](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3755)
- [Plate 8 x 11](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=728)
- [Baseplate 32 x 37](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3811a)

Baseplates also used to come in a lot of multiples of 5. Now they are all multiples of 8.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding odd lengths: Lego very recently started making [1 x 5 plates](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=78329#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) (and if you stack 3 of them, it's the same size as a brick). Otherwise, no.

[image: 1 x 5]